# comparison and equality of one of the two array

Tags: php, mysql

I want comparison and equality of one of the two array in  PHP

- $rows array from mysql database.
- $keywords array from url address.

  ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM posts_categories";
   $result = $conn->query($query);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $rows[] = $row['url'];

   }}
   $urla = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $url = parse_url($urla, PHP_URL_PATH);
   $urlu = urldecode($url);
   $keywords = preg_split("#/#", $urlu);

   if (in_array($keywords, $rows, true)) {
       echo "Yes!";
   }
  ```

Comment: I would suggest first look if the arrays are  of equal length and then check if the values  are equal.. you can use count for the first a loop within a loop for the second plus other methods....

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou  thanks. I used [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two arrays in PHP, you should take a closer look at the [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function.

Comment: thanks for your help. I used [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and it works now